What is the recommended way of publishing a non-packaged WinUI 3 app?
We have a WinUI 3 app that we would like to deliver to users in a non-packaged format using our installer creating tool that also includes another components of our product.
I set the WindowsPackageType tag to none in the .csproj file.
My question is what should I do with the WindowsAppSdkSelfContained and SelfContained tags. I understand the first one will include the  Windows App SDK Framework's contents in my build output. The second one will include the .net runtime in my build output. I know it is convenient to include them, although I am not sure that which one is the preferred way to use or maybe both.
But I am mostly concerned about using any of them because in that case the DLLs that come with the runtime/framework will be packed in my setup which means I have to sign those DLLs and I will be responsible for them if there would be any vulnerability or issue with them, which would mean a new release for us probably which our team would like to avoid. So we are considering to include the .net runtime's setup or Windows App SDK' s setup in our setup so that the user would be responsible for those.
What would be the recommended approach in this case?

This really depends on yourself. If you don't want to sign all the dlls, then you could choose to just package your app and let users download the runtime and app sdk by themself.
